# How can I add cumulative sum column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I use SqlExpress

Following is the query using which I get the attached result.

```
SELECT ReceiptId, Date, Amount, Fine, [Transaction]
FROM (
    SELECT ReceiptId, Date, Amount, 'DR' AS [Transaction]
    FROM ReceiptCRDR
    WHERE        (Amount > 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        ReceiptId, Date, Amount, 'CR' AS [Transaction]
    FROM            ReceiptCR
    WHERE        (Amount > 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        strInvoiceNo AS ReceiptId, CONVERT(datetime, dtInvoiceDt, 103) AS Date, floatTotal AS Amount,  'DR' AS [Transaction]
    FROM            tblSellDetails
) AS t
ORDER BY Date
```

**Result**

[image]

want a new column which would show balance amount.
For example. 1 Row should show -2500, 2nd should -3900, 3rd should -700 and so on.

basically, it requires previous row' Account column's data and carry out calculation based on transaction type.

Sample Result

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant rdbms. some sample data would be nice too.

Comment: Shouldn't fourth row of desired output return -1700 and then -1200 and -500? Also is there no true ordering mechanism such Date and TIme for transactions?

Comment: You are correct. The fourth row should be 1700. The ordering is based on date. if you look at my query there is ordering based on date.

Comment: But the date is not unique. Plus it is not in date time format: *YYYY-MM-DD*. Debit/credit transactions would matter in how they are processed especially within a singe day. Is there a transaction unique id to use?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that looks like `SQL-Server` , if you are using 2012+ , then use `SUM() OVER()` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.transactionType = 'DR' 
                THEN t.amount*-1
                ELSE t.amount END) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY t.date ORDER BY t.receiptId,t.TransactionType DESC) as Cumulative_Col
FROM (YourQuery Here) t
```

This will `SUM` the value when its `CR` and the `value*-1` when its `DR`

Right now I grouped by date, meaning each day will recalculate this column, if you want it for all time, replace the `OVER()` with this:

```
OVER(ORDER BY t.date,t.receiptId,t.TransactionType DESC) as Cumulative_Col
```

Also, I didn't understand why in the same date, for the same `ReceiptId` `DR` is calculated before `CR` , I've add it to the order by but if thats not what you want then explain the logic better.

Comment: Its because if a customer has made a part payment, so the balance amount will get saved as DR and paid amount as CR

Comment: That I understand, but why you first calculate deduct `DR` and then add `CR` ? Why not the other way around? Ordered by which column? . Anyways, this should work. @MARKANDBhatt

Comment: I get error: "Incorrect syntax near Order" I use SQLExpress. May be SqlExpress 2008

Comment: Sagi's Code works for Sqlserver2012. I use SqlExpress 2008. So when i try to apply his query, I get error : "Incorrect Syntax near Order"